# How to reorder the bars of a geom_bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tidyverse

So I have data as such:

```
df <- structure(list(bin = structure(c(14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "K", "EE", "F", 
"G", "H", "I", "SS", "AR", 
"W", "D", "T"), class = "factor"), count = c(514L, 
504L, 145L, 131L, 96L, 80L, 63L, 38L, 34L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 18L, 
18L), pct = c("30.0%", "29.5%", "8.5%", "7.7%", "5.6%", "4.7%", 
"3.7%", "2.2%", "2.0%", "1.5%", "1.4%", "1.2%", "1.1%", "1.1%"
)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And I would like to plot them, but ordered on `count` but I can't get it to work. Used `reorder` to no avail...

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=count, x=reorder(as.factor(bin),count), label = pct)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  aes(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(bin), 15), count) +
  geom_col(fill = "mediumpurple2")+
  labs(x = "", y = "Count", fill = "")+
  lims(y = c(0,550)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),     #move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,     #nudge above top of bar
            size = 3) +
  theme_hc() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

I've come across this issue several times, so an explaination as to what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful!

Comment: You've defined the default `x` mapping twice, once in the `ggplot()` and once in the bare `aes()`. You only did reorder in the first, but only the last will be used and you did not reorder in the `aes()`. The last mapping wins, they are not combined in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest next slight change in your approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
ggplot(df, aes(y=count, x=reorder(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(bin), 15),count), label = pct)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  geom_col(fill = "mediumpurple2")+
  labs(x = "", y = "Count", fill = "")+
  lims(y = c(0,550)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),     #move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,     #nudge above top of bar
            size = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]

**Bonus:** If you want labels in right placement try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=count, x=reorder(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(bin), 15),count), label = pct)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  geom_col(fill = "mediumpurple2")+
  labs(x = "", y = "Count", fill = "")+
  lims(y = c(0,550)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),     #move to center of bars
            hjust=-0.5,vjust=-0.25,     #nudge above top of bar
            size = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]